# Communication between widgets (flex)?

Tags: sql-server, java, arcgis-flex-api, flex, widget

I'm new in flex, and I'm working on a web mapping application using flex 4.6, Java, and sqlserver as database, I'm just trying to make a communication between wigdets.

I would like to copy each selected item of my combobox in widget1, and show it in the textinput in widget2, I just followed this steps explained by Robert here http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/138...+communication but no luck, the problem that I'm facing is that I can't call components of the first widget (textinput, button....) from the second widget, they are often underlined !!

At jump you found the change I made,

Widget 1

```
var layoutArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            private function widgetCommunication1():void
            {
                addSharedData("Liste des chapitres", layoutArr); 
            }
```

Widget 2

```
icationCompleteHandler(event)" 
                   initialize="basewidget1_initializeHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

                        import com.esri.viewer.AppEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    protected function basewidget1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                ViewerContainer.addEventListener(AppEvent.DATA_PUBLISH, sharedDataUpdated);
            }

 private function sharedDataUpdated(event:AppEvent):void
            {
                var data:Object = event.data;               
                if (data.key == "Liste des chapitres")

                {
                    dplist.selectedIndex = ***IntChap***.text;
                } 
            }   

]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:DropDownList id="dplist" x="10" y="10" width="282" height="26" labelField="IntituleChap" dataProvider="{RemoteRapportDao.Selection.lastResult}" change="dplist_changeHandler(event)" ></s:DropDownList>
```

IntChap which is bold & italic is the textinput in widget1 , i got it underlined in widget 2, even if i made this communication

Can anyone tell me what i'm messing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was more than 6 months, i don't remember exactly what problem i faced, but, i'm sure that wasn't a big problem, maybe i just forgotten some simple thing, so i recommand you to follow the steps explained in this link : `http://web.zone.ee/bespiva/`
About version, i used Arcgis 10.1, Flex 4.6